# Removing dynamic divs made with JS on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code knowledge is very limited, comes from CodeHS and Codecademy so bear with me.

So I am trying to make a list of numbers, that can be deleted on click. So far so good with the number list, but I still can't figure how to remove them when I click the div box.

I know theres JSFiddle, but I think this is best I could do:
http://www.codecademy.com/rfabrega/codebits/xZ61aJ

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=203">
<title>Lista Mundial</title>

<style>
    .divContainer {
        width: 35px;
        height: 25px;
        border: solid 1px #c0c0c0;  
        background-color: #e1e1e1;
        font-family: verdana;  
        color: #000;
        float: left;
    }

    .text {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: verdana;
        color: black;
        margin-top: 4px;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    for(var i = 1; i <= 639; i++){
        var divTag = document.createElement("div");
        divTag.id = i;
        divTag.className = "divContainer";
        document.body.appendChild(divTag);
        var pTg = document.createElement("p");
        pTg.setAttribute("align", "center");
        pTg.className = "text";
        pTg.innerHTML = (i);
        document.getElementById(i).appendChild(pTg);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create a function on click that deletes the target div tag:
so in your code, after creating the div element. insert this:

```
divTag.onclick = function(){this.parentNode.removeChild(this)};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').hide();
    $("body").on("click",".divContainer",function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```